# how to directly parse jsondata using JSONObject in java?

Tags: java, android, json

how to directly parse JSONdata using JSONObject in java as my JSON Data don't have any JSONArray .

JSONData:-

```
{{
"id": 481,
"date": "2016-12-30T13:56:10",
"date_gmt": "2016-12-30T13:56:10",
"guid": {
"rendered": "http://www.mytrendin.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/read-           1710011_1280.jpg"
},
"modified": "2016-12-30T13:56:20",
"modified_gmt": "2016-12-30T13:56:20",
"slug": "read-1710011_1280",
"type": "attachment",
"link": "http://www.mytrendin.com/increase-child-development/read-1710011_1280/",
"title": {
"rendered": "child development"
}}
```

java code

```
 jsonObject = new JSONObject(results);


            for(i=0;i<jsonObject.length();i++){

                jsonObject=jsonObject.getJSONObject();


                j = jsonObject.getString("type");

              //  mainActivityModel.setId();

            }
```

Comment: Json is invalid

Comment: paste complete json here , use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ for checking  whether your json is valid

Comment: You should have rather searched for some good tutorial, there are loads of them available; because even if someone provides you with the code, you may or may not understand it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **json is incorrect**.

```
{ 
"id": 481, 
"date": "2016-12-30T13:56:10", 
"date_gmt": "2016-12-30T13:56:10", 
"guid": { "rendered": "http://www.mytrendin.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/read- 1710011_1280.jpg" },
 "modified": "2016-12-30T13:56:20", "modified_gmt": "2016-12-30T13:56:20", 
"slug": "read-1710011_1280",
 "type": "attachment",
 "link": "http://www.mytrendin.com/increase-child-development/read-1710011_1280/", "title": { "rendered": "child development" }
}
```

You can parse json by this.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject guid=obj.getJSONObject("guid");
```

To get json object you will call getJSONObject() and to get String you will call getString()

And if you need to parse a json Array

`JSONArray json_arr = new JSONArray(results); 
for(i=0;i<json_arr.length();i++){ 
JSONObject jsonObject=json_arr.getJSONObject(i); 
}`

Comment: this was just an example . you please tell me how to iterate using forloop

Comment: It's a json object you don't need a for loop to parse this.. If this would be a json array then you will be definitely need for loop

Comment: You will get all values from this json result by calling getString()

Answer (score 0):

go through this tutorial it can help you in understanding json parsing 
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/